# Is there a way to add water to a Unity3d project that is combatible with mobile platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) project, I have [Unity Pro](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) which comes with water4. I realize I will not be able to use this if I'm trying to make a game that works on mobile devices. Does anyone have an idea or way of making water (and allowing it to move) to look more realistic then just simply painting it on the terrain and won't crash the game on the mobile device. Also I am creating scripts in unityscript.

Comment: The simple water assets in the `Water (Basic)` pack should work on mobile devices, iirc.

Comment: If you're really worried about using up too many resources, you could always try simply sticking a water texture on a plane, then animate that texture so the water looks like its flowing in a certain direction. It's not the prettiest water, but it's the least resource costly I can think of. Otherwise as Jerdak said, Water(Basic) is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This water package looks pretty good, is for Mobile, non-pro and is on the Asset store.

http://u3d.as/content/grespon/easy-water/2Q8